# Read-only clause for a query

Tags: sql-server, readonly

I am wanting to allow users, via an ASP page, to run a query on my database, however I want this query to be restricted to read-only.

I will try to detect as much as I can in the ASP itself (detect words drop, update, delete etc.) and not run the query in these scenarios, but, is there a way I can just append a flag to the query when my ASP submits it to have it execute as read-only regardless of its content?

I realise that, if this is possible, update/delete/drop statements will error - this is fine.

I also want to avoid setting the whole DB or even table as read-only.

I also don't want to replicate my database in any form.

Thankyou for your help.

Dan

Comment: Why not use stored procedures? Otherwise, use a user/login which only have select permissions

Comment: Hi, the user/password idea is a good one, and I hadn't thought of this; thanks!  As for the stored procedure, I want them to be able to pen the query themselves, so I don't understand if or how a stored procedure can help here.

Comment: If you're allowing your users to submit arbitrary SQL, it's still possible to be malicious when all you're allowed to do is read. I.e. I can construct an arbitrarily large query which will lock up all of your tables and consume most of the server resources as it attempts to construct billions of rows of results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thankyou Allan S. Hansen, I used the username/password method to good effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be dynamic. Main problem - sql injection.
I recommend this way:

1. create database role [DYNAMIC_SQL]. Give required select permissions on tables to [DYNAMIC_SQL] role.
2. create database user without login [dynamic_sql_proxy]. Map with [DYNAMIC_SQL] role.
3. create procedure [dynamic_sql__call] with hardcoded execution rights as [dynamic_sql_proxy]. Pass your custom query to this procedure.

Scripts:
(1)

```
USE [your_db]
GO
CREATE ROLE [DYNAMIC_SQL]
GO


GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[your_table] TO [DYNAMIC_SQL] AS [dbo]
***
```

(2)

```
CREATE USER [dynamic_sql_proxy] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
ALTER ROLE [DYNAMIC_SQL] ADD MEMBER [dynamic_sql_proxy]
```

(3)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dynamic_sql__call]
     @err_code      INT             OUTPUT
    ,@err_msg       NVARCHAR(4000)  OUTPUT
    ,@sql           NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dynamic_sql_proxy'
AS
BEGIN

    SET @err_code   =   0;
    SET @err_msg    =   SPACE(0);

    BEGIN TRY

        EXEC(@sql);

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT 'Please handle your error';

    END CATCH;

    RETURN @err_code;   

END;
```